# Problems connecting to a friend's private server

Tags: vpn, isp

Whenever I try to connect to a server hosted on my friend's network, the request times out. This also happens when he tries to connect to a server hosted on my network. Nobody else who tries to connect to my network or his network has any problems. This happens whenever either of us host a game server or VPN.

So far the only thing that I can think of that is different between him and my other friends is that both he and I have Comcast, where my friends use other ISPs. As far as I can tell, neither of us are refusing connections or have the other person blacklisted or anything like that.

What might be causing this problem, and how could I fix it?

Comment: Try traceroute or pathping (on windows) to see if its a routing issue or if the server is reachable at all.

Comment: If you connect to the same VPN hosted neither of you, are you then able to, connect to one another?

Comment: I removed the guess, and I didn't change another word. Perhaps now you can see the answer. My answer is not a comment, and it never was a comment. It is a legitimate answer because it is a problem which the ISPs, especially cable ISPs, cause. Gamers in the same neighborhood have this problem all the time.

Answer (score -1):

It is common for ISPs to restrict their residential customers from directly communicating. You can contact Comcast about this problem,

Comment: The guess is not the answer. The answer is that it is a common practice for ISPs to not allow their residential customer to connect to each other. That was the practice which Comcast used when they were the cable company here. The guess is what they will say about it, and that is not the answer.

Comment: I removed the guess, and I didn't change another word. Perhaps now you can see the answer. My answer is not a comment, and it never was a comment. It is a legitimate answer because it is a problem which the ISPs, especially cable ISPs, cause. Gamers in the same neighborhood have this problem all the time.